# Python 3 - Reference Class as Drop-In Replacement for Deeply Immutable (Hashable) Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, publish-subscribe

Is there any way to:

1. Override assignment in a way that doesn't just kill Python programmers' expectations?

   ```python
   port = IntContainer(80)
   port = 8080             # set the IntContainer contents to 8080
                           # instead of changing what the port name references
                           # from the IntContainer(80) to int(8080)
   ```
2. Override rich comparators such that the order of the arguments to the binary comparison operator doesn't matter?

   ```python
   port = IntContainer(80)
   port < 80               # False
   80 > port               # TypeError
   ```

@BrenBarn:

What version of Python? I'm using 3.4.3:

```python
class Foo(object):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.value = other

foo = Foo(1)
foo < 1         # False
1 > foo         # raise TypeError()
```

## Why I want this:

1. I want a dynamic HTTP server process configuration object. PUT and POST requests to a certain control port at a certain URL should update the configuration object, and have it propagate.
2. I don't think polling the config object is a good idea, especially in the context of concurrency. For composability, where do you lock without risk of deadlocks? If config objects share a global lock (which is fine for the expected rate of mutation for config), each read still acquires said lock. If every `logging` message needs to set the `Handler` level, that's obviously bad.
3. Therefore, I want a pub-sub config object. This allows the config user to locally cache and update the cached value on pub. This has the added benefit of being concurrency-safe without locks - pub messages can always be internally consistent. (Composition takes some care, but it's not that bad.)

I've already written the code for this for the `list` and `dict` container config types. I use the `blinker` lib for signaling. These objects are smart; signals propagate from leaves up towards to any objects that contain them (not trees or forests since these are re-composable). Each broadcasts to their subscribers, which include other container configs, as well as actual user subscribers. For example:

```python
def receive_a(signal):
    print('Object 'a' received {} event at path {}; prev: {!r}, curr: {!r}'.format(
        signal.type, signal.path, signal.prev, signal.curr
    ))
config_dict_a = ConfigDict()
config_dict_a.connect(receive_a)

def receive_b(signal):
    print('Object 'b' received {} event at path {}; prev: {!r}, curr: {!r}'.format(
        signal.type.name, signal.path, signal.prev, signal.curr
    ))
config_dict_b = ConfigDict()
config_dict_b.connect(receive_b)

config_dict_a['b'] = config_dict_b
# Object 'a' received INSERT event at path ('b',); prev: None, curr: {}
# Object 'a' received UPDATE event at path (); prev: {}, curr: {'b': {}}
config_dict_b['foo'] = 42
# Object 'b' received INSERT event at path ('foo',); prev: None, curr: 42
# Object 'b' received UPDATE event at path (); prev: {}, curr: {'foo': 42}
# Object 'a' received INSERT event at path ('b', 'foo'); prev: None, curr: 42
# Object 'a' received UPDATE event at path ('b',); prev: {}, curr: {'foo': 42}
# Object 'a' received UPDATE event at path (); prev: {'b': {}}, curr: {'b': {'foo': 42}}
del config_a['b']['foo']
# Object 'b' received DELETE event at path ('foo',); prev: 42, curr: None
# Object 'b' received UPDATE event at path (); prev: {'foo': 42}, curr: {}
# Object 'a' received DELETE event at path ('b', 'foo',); prev: 42, curr: None
# Object 'a' received UPDATE event at path ('b',); prev: {'foo': 42}, curr: {}
# Object 'a' received UPDATE event at path (); prev: {'b': {'foo': 42}}, curr: {'b': {}}
```

Just subscribe to the one you want, and listen for the exact path you want. This is useful in particular for configuration at the Python process level when there are sub-services or workers. The process can carve up its config, recompose to a new root config specific to each constituent part, and hand it to the parts for them to subscribe to.

Safety for composing higher-level messages from lower-level messages only requires a local lock, not a global one.

## What the issue is:

`list` and `dict`, as container types, are inherently a form of reference type - that's what makes them mutable. My `Config<Container>` objects are readable from the outside the same way you `__getitem__` on anything. They extend `collections.abc` stuff, so they work. You can also write to them the same way without any funky `self.set(value)` notation.

But deeply immutable scalars (`Hashable`), are not. This includes `int`, `str`, even `NoneType`. These cannot be drop-in replacements:

1. I can't override assignment, for good reason (it's insane).

   ```python
   int_a = ConfigInt()
   int_a = 2
   # swap out what the name 'int_a' refers to, or modify the internal contents?
   # obviously crazy
   ```
2. I need to support `set(value)` anyways, so whatever on `1.`.
3. I can't do comparison without subclassing the built-in type.

   - To extend the built-in is a lie - the expectation for each of those types is that they're immutable.
   - Also, there's no virtual subclassing to extend equality or comparison for the left-right swap problem:

     ```
     port = ConfigInt()
     port > 40               # True
     40 < port               # TypeError()
     ```

None of this is insurmountable, but nice libraries are nice to you. I'd really like to address this. Especially for those cases where a scalar is all a worker needs - like a Flask greenlet or something - the scalar is the top-level object, we shouldn't have to wrap it in a `dict`.

## Other questions

- IDK. Thoughts? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Your question is somewhat long and confusing.  I can't tell what you are actually asking.  Can you simplify your question to a direct statement of what you're trying to implement, ideally with fake-code examples?  Also, what you say in your last example is incorrect; if you override `__eq__` on `ConfigInt` in an appropriate way, then `port == 80` and `80 == port` will both work.

Comment: Thanks, @BrenBarn. Sorry, I hate it when there are questions with no context, because often the desired solution is based on incorrect assumptions. I'll fix. As for ``__eq__``, I'll include a broken example.

Comment: Can't reproduce the ``__eq__`` thing. I must be smoking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Override assignment in a way that doesn't just kill Python programmers' expectations?

No, you can't override plain assignment to a bare name at all.  As you suggested later in your question, you need to use a `set` method or the like.

> Override rich comparators such that the order of the arguments to the binary comparison operator doesn't matter?

That already works:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Foo):
            return self.val < other.val
        else:
            return self.val < other

>>> Foo(3) < 10
True
>>> 10 > Foo(3)
True
```

Of course, you may have to think a bit about what you want the behavior to be when comparing to other types, and what counts as "other types".  Here I just compare the "stored value" of the `Foo` object directly with the other value, if that other value is not also a Foo.

Comment: Addressed yours in the original question with code formatting. What Python version are you using? I'm using 3.4.3 CPython on OSX.

Comment: @alyssackwan: The implementation of `__lt__` you used is different than mine.  Take a look at the difference.  Your version won't work for comparing actual `Foo` instances.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it in my test, but am still seeing the TypeError(). Is this a CPython on OSX bug? I found PEP 207. Is there a more recent PEP?

Comment: @alyssackwan: No, that should be the correct behavior.  Are you saying that using the exact same simple example I showed in my answer doesn't give the same result?

Comment: Yes. What's your env? Maybe I have a weirdly bad build. I just ran Homebrew pyenv and have pyenv virtualenv on top. I would imagine this type of bug would cause havoc.

Comment: OK, tested on CentOS with no problems. Sorry for the nonsense question. Thanks for sticking with me. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I would just double-check your setup.  It may be you're not running the Python version you think you are.  I don't use a Mac though so I don't really know.

Comment: Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep  6 2015, 20:45:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
:(.